# Getting error while using 2-d array through vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

I was coding on leetcode and while doing so I got this error - "Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)" Can anyone please help me where I am doing wrong. Below is my code

```
class Solution {
public:
int uniquePaths(int m, int n) {
    vector<vector<int>> ans;
    vector<int> help;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            vector<int> temp;
            if(i==0||j==0)
            {
                temp.push_back(1);
            }
            else
            {
                temp.push_back(temp[j-1]+help[j]);
            }
            help=temp;
            ans.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    return ans[m-1][n-1];
}
```

Comment: *I was coding on leetcode* -- Get your own local compiler and test the code.  Don't rely on a website to have a compiler, debugger, and other tools available.

Comment: `temp.push_back(temp[j-1]+help[j]);` -- Change that to this: `temp.push_back(temp.at(j-1) + help.at(j));`.  Does that give you a different error, more like `std::out_of_range` exception?  Also, what if `m` or `n` is 0?  This line: `return ans[m-1][n-1];` accesses an invalid index.  As a matter of fact, that also can be checked using `at()` by doing this:  `return ans.at(m-1).at(n-1);`

Comment: so basically difference between ans[m] and ans.at(m) is that at function first checks whether this index is valid or not and then returns value whereas ans[m] directly returns value right ?

Comment: The difference is that `at()` does a check to see if the index is in range.  If not in range, then a `std::out_of_range` exception is thrown, otherwise `at()` returns the value.  Using `[]` will not check if the value is in range, and if the value is not in range, then the behavior of the code is undefined.

Comment: `temp` can never contain more than one element, since it's created anew for every iteration of the innermost loop. That's probably not what you intended. In particular, `temp` is empty when `temp[j-1]` is evaluated.